# Jquery mobile Shockwave loaded from script tag does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery mobile site. one of the tags in the body is a javascript script tag with a src param . The Javascript does some magic and returns an embedded shockwave object in an iframe in the page (this is a 3rd party script so I have no control over what or how it works).  This works fine on a non-Ajax loaded page, but even in my desktop browser this will not work with a page in the JQuery mobile app. I do not get an error of any sort and I can see in the Network tab that the Javascript is found successfully.

Comment: Some code could be helpful, the more, the merrier. Does the script return a shockwave object within an iframe, ready to be applied into the existing DOM, or do you try to insert the shockwave object into an existing iframe?

Comment: I do not have to do anything. It inserts the object in the DOM.  There really is not code I can show you other than <script src="PATH_TO_SCRIPT"></script>.  Like I mentioned the script is not mine.  on the non-mobile side it inserts an iframe with a full html document in it. If I go to the non JQuery Mobile website with my phone it recognizes that it is a mobile device and presents a mobile version just fine. Only within jQuery Mobile does it do nothing, which to me says it is recognizing that it is a mobile device but that the returned object then does nothing.  Sorry I can't be more help.